# Adding Redis Caching to Identity Server 6

Tags: c#, redis, duende-identity-server

I've upgraded an Identity Server based project from the original Identity Server 4, to [Duende's Identity Server 6](https://duendesoftware.com/products/identityserver).
The upgrade appears to have worked but I've had to remove some existing code in order to get it to work.

This is the configuration we used to have in `Startup.cs`

```cs
services.AddIdentityServer()
   .AddOperationalStore(options => {
      options.RedisConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("Redis");
      options.Db = 1;
   })
   .AddRedisCaching(options => {
       options.RedisConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("Redis");
       options.KeyPrefix = "custom_prefix";
   })
   .AddSigningCredential(new X509Certificate2(Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "secretauth.pfx"), "secret_key"))
   .AddUserStore() // Custom User Store
   .AddResourceStore<CustomResourceStore>()
   .AddClientStore<CustomClientStore>();
```

The prior version made use of [IdentityServer4.Contrib.RedisStore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IdentityServer4.Contrib.RedisStore/1.0.0) which is no longer available to us as of Identity Server 6.

This means our new implementation doesn't have the option to add Redis caching for our session data and I can't see a Duende-relevant nuget package that might provide it.

Leaving us with just this;

```cs
services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
{
    options.LicenseKey = Configuration.GetValue<string>(key: "Duende.IdentityServer:licenseKey");
})
.AddUserStore() // Custom User Store
.AddClientStore<CustomClientStore>()
.AddResourceStore<CustomResourceStore>();
```

Am I missing a potentially useful Nuget extension package somewhere or do we need to look at a whole new way of implementing Redis caching on our operational data store?

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I'm guessing you went with a different solution or wrote your own implementations for ISigningKeyStore

Comment: @Stuart Frankish, were you able to solve the problem?